# Jquery else not executing even when If statement is false

Tags: jquery, css

I have no idea why the "else" part of this code isn't working. The "if" part works, box-shadow appears like it should when I scroll down a bit. But when I scroll back up, the "else" doesn't execute and the shadow remains.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (scrollTop > 0) {
        $('#panels-holder').css('box-shadow', "0px 5px 100px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5)");
    }
    else {
        $('#panels-holder').css('box-Shadow', "0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0)");
    }
});
```

Also, could I just shorten it to this when removing the shadow:

```
$('#panels-holder').css('box-Shadow', "");
```

Thanks! I feel like I'm missing something super obvious... especially when I can't find another question/answer about if/else not executing that's related to scroll events.

Comment: may be capital S  ?

Comment: it is often advised to use length when checking values in javascript. Can you do if(scrollTop.Length >0)

Comment: haha so it WAS something really stupid... yeah it's the capital S my bad

Answer (score 0):

So as Suresh Atta pointed out, I messed up capitalization... silly me, I've been stuck on this tiny snippet of code for 1 hour.

```
$('#panels-holder').css('box-shadow', "");
```

Comment: //kinda off-topic: We've all been there and will be again :D